# how to calculate the speed ratio (Rotational speed to advancing speed) in friction stir welding

Tags: friction, welding

I am a student and I work in the friction stir welding of a hardened aluminium alloy 7075-T6, and I want to confirm about this information before I put it in the article.

I found in the literature that there are two ways of calculating the ratio of speed:

ratio=advancing speed/(rotational speed*pin diameter)

and the other is:

ratio=Rotational speed/advancing speed

what should I choose?

Comment: I scanned the titles of articles via a Google search; it would appear that you're best off picking any definition you want but being very clear in your writing what the definition in use is.